# The square of a maximal ideal $m$ equals $m$ itself, i.e, $m/m^2=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

> Fact: if $M$ is an $A$-module and $I $ is an ideal of $A$, then $M/IM\simeq M\otimes_A A/I$

Letting $m$ be a maximal ideal of $A$, $M=m$ and $I=m$, we have $m/m^2\simeq m\otimes_A A/m$. Taking any $a\in m$, then $a\otimes [1]=1\otimes [a]=1\otimes  [0]=0$, so $m\otimes_A A/m=0$, therefore $m/m^2=0$.

I know something is wrong here, since for $A=\mathbb{Z}$ and $m=(2)\subset  \mathbb{Z}$, we have $(2)/(2)^2\neq 0$, but I can't find what I did wrong.

Comment: The equality $a\otimes [1]=1\otimes [a]$ is wrong. In fact, the second member does not mean anything because $1\not\in m$. For example $2\mathbb{Z}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z/2Z}\simeq \mathbb{Z}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z/2Z}\simeq\mathbb{Z/2Z}$ since $2\mathbb{Z}\simeq\mathbb{Z}$. So this group is not zero.

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [Guidelines for good use of $\LaTeX$ in question titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730).

Comment: Thanks, @MartinSleziak, just edited it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact you quote is true.

What's wrong is $a\otimes[1]=1\otimes[a]$, because $a\in m$, but $1\notin m$, so you can't use that $a=1a$ and switch $a$ to the other side of $\otimes$.

Just for completeness, the fact stems from the comparison of the exact sequences in the following commutative diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
{} @. M\otimes_A I @>>> M\otimes_A A @>>> M\otimes_A A/I @>>> 0 \\
@. @VVV @VVV @VVV @. \\
0 @>>> IM @>>> M @>>> M/IM @>>> 0
\end{CD}
$$
A simple diagram chasing, using the fact that $M\otimes_A I\to IM$ is surjective and $M\otimes_AA\to M$ is bijective ends the proof that $M\otimes_A A/I\to M/IM$ is an isomorphism.